# Unable to open WPF solution in Visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to open a WPF solution with Visual Studio 2019 but getting an error message "Project file can not be loaded"

In Detailed Information section, I can see the below message.

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\Sdk not
>   found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or
>   increase the version specified in global.json.

I have already installed SDK 2.2.402 but WindowsDesktop is missing in it. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there any update for your issue? Did you install the .Net Core 3.* to try? What mm8 said is right, by using the .NET Core 3.0 SDK component Windows Desktop, you can port your WinForms and WPF. Here is a doc [.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0) which you can refer to for details

Answer (score 2):

`WindowsDesktop` including WPF is supported in .NET Core **3**.x and onwards so you should download the 3.1.300 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

.NET Core 2.2 doesn't support WPF.